# How to access a secured API in the frontend?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

There is a lot of good content on the internet that explains how to secure a Spring API with Keycloak: Create a Client that represents the API Service in Keycloak and use a link like the one below to get the access and refresh token:

```
<Domain>/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/auth/{some parameters}
```

This yields both tokens. So far so good.

Now, however, I am not sure how the flow for the frontend accessing the API should look like.

- Should the frontend directly access this endpoint and, therefore, obtain the access and refresh token? That would mean that the API can only have the access-type public because there is no way to store the client (the API) secret securely.
- Or should there be a third server that somehow stores the refresh token for each user, that the user can call if his access token is no longer valid. This server would then use the client's refresh token (and the client secret that could be stored securely, since it would be in the backend) to get a new access token from Keycloak and would forward it to the user.

I guess the main question that I am asking is, whether the client/user should get the refresh token.

If one needs to implement a logic according to the second option, I would be interested in a link or description of how something like this can be done in Spring.

Answer (score 1):

I think, in either case you need to use the Authorization Code Flow. The implicit flow, which was recommended for SPAs (frontends without a backend server) in former versions of OAuth2 must not be used anymore.

The best option is to have a backend server, so the user retrieves the auth code via redirection and the backend server exchanges this auth code with the access and refresh tokens (and keep them without forwarding them to the frontend).

If there is no backend in place and your frontend needs to retrieve and hold the tokens directly, I would recommend to use the Authorization Code Flow with a public client and the PKCE extension (which - put simply - ensures that the entity asking for the auth code is the same as the entity asking for the tokens and that the auth code was not stolen and used by a foreign entity). There are several sources with more detailed explanations, which might help you, for example: https://auth0.com/docs/flows/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce

Hope this helps you with your architectural considerations.